# React Native Application is not touchable and shows warning

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, debugging, mobile-application

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIpGf.png)

The Inputs are not focusing when I touch and button is also not touchable, Basically I can see my app, but can't interact with it. It also shows an warning about SSR Provider. I reloaded it but still its in the same state.

Comment: Show your code and what libs you use, pls

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.